# How can I make a "toothpaste" style line in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, stroke

One of the tasks at hand is to create an almost 3d effect when drawing. It gives the impression that the stroke is coming from a tube:

[image: A tube stroke]

How do you create this effect with Canvas?

To give some background, instead of drawing with Canvas, I would use a circular "brush" texture, and then interpolate the circles on a dynamic texture.  This gives me the same effect but it is painfully slow on mobile devices.

Comment: In short: you are wanting to add highlights to the top/left edges and shadows to the bottom/right. Easiest way to do this: create your shape as a mask, offset up and left, intersect with the original mask, blur, and then screen blend mode white. Repeat with down to the right followed by a multiply with black.

Comment: or you just want to switch from an image+Js to canvas+Js, using the same circle texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You could use a shadow to create a 3d effect:**

You will need to draw 2 lines with the 2nd line having a shadow.

- Draw a thick white line with round linecap
- Draw a second line with a shadow. Have its shadow appear the bottom of that first line.

[image]

The "trick" here is to have only the 2nd line's shadow appear (the 2nd line itself will not appear). This is done by drawing a second line way above the canvas and using shadowOffsetY to push that second line's shadow onto the canvas on the bottom of the first line.

While shadowing is a fairly expensive operation, it's far less expensive than building a series of images that form your toothpaste.

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// floodfill the canvas with purple
ctx.fillStyle='#9933cc';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);

// draw a wide white line with round linecap
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(150,75);
ctx.lineTo(250,125);
ctx.lineWidth=25;
ctx.lineCap='round';
ctx.strokeStyle='white';
ctx.stroke();

// set shadowing to black with 10px blur size
ctx.shadowColor='black'
ctx.shadowBlur=10;

// draw the shadow way below the line
ctx.shadowOffsetY=212.5;

// Draw a line up off the top of the canvas
// The line will not be visible
// But the line's shadow will be visible
//     over the bottom of the wide white line
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(42,50-200);
ctx.lineTo(150,75-200);
ctx.lineTo(258,127-200);
ctx.lineWidth=10;
ctx.strokeStyle='red';
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll still want to use the circular brush texture.

```
var texture = new Image;
texture.src = 'brush.png'
```

Then you'll need to create your canvas and add it to your page somewhere, something like:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 300;
document.getElementByID('parentDiv').appendChild(canvas)
```

Then you'll need an event listener like this to draw that to the canvas.

```
function moveMouse(xx,yy){
     canvas.context.drawImage(texture, xx, yy)
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    if(e.clientX){
        var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        if(rect)            moveMouse(e.clientX - rect.left, e.clientY - rect.top)
        else                moveMouse(e.clientX  - this.offsetLeft, e.clientY - this.offsetTop);
    }else if(e.offsetX)     moveMouse(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    else if(e.layerX)       moveMouse(e.layerX, e.layerY);
    else console.warn("Couldn't Determine Mouse Coordinates");
})
```

Good Luck!